# Group By Column Name in Json Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to group the column name of ccSection in the below json. I need output as Tab1, Tab2. Please help me. I am new of this field..

```
var temp=[
    {
        "cfId": 3,
        "ccDisplayOrder": 1,
        "ccControlID": 1,
        "ccKey": "stName",
        "ccSection": "Tab1"
    },
    {
        "cfId": 3,
        "ccDisplayOrder": 2,
        "ccControlID": 2,
        "ccKey": "stOwner",
        "ccSection": "Tab1"
    },
    {
        "cfId": 3,
        "ccDisplayOrder": 3,
        "ccControlID": 3,
        "ccKey": "stBegin",
        "ccSection": "Tab2"
    },
    {
        "cfId": 3,
        "ccDisplayOrder": 4,
        "ccControlID": 4,
        "ccKey": "stEnd",
        "ccSection": "Tab2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output format you're trying to achieve as well as adding any code you've written yourself in an attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var temp = [....] //your array of objects
var hash = {}
for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
 if( ! hash[temp[i].ccSection]){
    hash[temp[i].ccSection] = []
  }
  hash[temp[i].ccSection].push(temp[i])
}
console.log(hash.Tab1)
console.log(hash.Tab2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's working find. But i need the output as Tab1 and Tab2 only instead of grouping records......

Comment: what that mean ?
you can say
Tab1 = hash.Tab1 - 
Tab2 = hash.Tab2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by underscore so easily.

```
var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, function(d){return d.ccSection});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/caa3xd9h/)
**using jquery**

```
var groups = {};
var data=[
    {
        "cfId": 3,
        "ccDisplayOrder": 1,
        "ccControlID": 1,
        "ccKey": "stName",
        "ccSection": "Tab1"
    },
    {
        "cfId": 3,
        "ccDisplayOrder": 2,
        "ccControlID": 2,
        "ccKey": "stOwner",
        "ccSection": "Tab1"
    },
    {
        "cfId": 3,
        "ccDisplayOrder": 3,
        "ccControlID": 3,
        "ccKey": "stBegin",
        "ccSection": "Tab2"
    },
    {
        "cfId": 3,
        "ccDisplayOrder": 4,
        "ccControlID": 4,
        "ccKey": "stEnd",
        "ccSection": "Tab2"
    }
]
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var level = item.ccSection;

    delete item.ccSection;

    if(groups[level]) {
        groups[level].push(item);
    } else {
        groups[level] = [item];
    }
});

console.log(groups);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ekdnc8g/)